# SD across multiple columns with NA data grouped by participant

Tags: r, multiple-columns, na, standard-deviation

I have 3 columns. The first column is the participant number. The other two are reaction time (RT) data with NAs in them. I want to get the standard deviation across the two columns to end up with one column that has the standard deviation for each participant of the data that is logged in the two RT columns.
The reason why there are NAs is because the participant column has multiple rows for one participant with the reaction time for each corresponding trial.

This is what the data looks like.

```
 participant BlackGood_rt WhiteGood_rt
   <fct>              <dbl>        <dbl>
 1 78370             NA            NA   
 2 78370             NA            NA   
 3 78370             NA            NA   
 4 78370             NA            NA   
 5 78370             NA            NA   
 6 78370             NA            NA   
 7 78370             NA            NA   
 8 78370             NA            NA   
 9 78370             NA            NA   
10 78370             NA            NA   
11 78370             NA            NA   
12 78370             NA            NA   
13 78370             NA            NA   
14 78370             NA            NA   
15 78370             NA            NA   
16 78370             NA            NA   
17 78370             NA            NA   
18 78370             NA            NA   
19 78370             NA            NA   
20 78370             NA            NA   
21 78370             NA            NA   
22 78370             NA            NA   
23 78370             NA            NA   
24 78370             NA            NA   
25 78370             NA            NA   
26 78370             NA            NA   
27 78370             NA            NA   
28 78370             NA            NA   
29 78370             NA            NA   
30 78370             NA            NA   
31 78370             NA            NA   
32 78370             NA             7.63
33 78370              4.60         NA   
34 78370             NA            NA   
35 78370             NA            NA   
36 78370              3.05         NA   
37 78370             NA             2.10
38 78370             NA            NA   
39 78370              1.95         NA   
40 78370             NA            NA   
41 78370             NA            NA   
42 78370             NA             2.25
43 78370             NA            NA   
44 78370             NA            NA   
45 78370             NA            NA   
46 78370             NA            NA   
47 78370             NA            NA   
48 78370              1.50         NA   
49 78370              1.20         NA   
50 78370              0.916        NA
```

I tried

```
BWGood_sd <- BWGood %>% 
  group_by(participant) %>% 
  summarise(across(BlackGood_rt:WhiteGood_rt, ~ sd(.x, na.rm = TRUE)))
```

And got this error message

```
Error in `across()`:
! Must only be used inside data-masking verbs like `mutate()`, `filter()`, and `group_by()`.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Comment: I cant recreate this error with example data, could you share the output of `dput(BWGood)`? Also, could you clarify - do you want the SD of all values from both columns for each participant? That is how I am interpreting "the standard deviation across the two columns to end up with one column that has the standard deviation for each participant of the data that is logged in the two RT columns". If you provide a desired output it would help clarify

Comment: This might be an error caused by using the wrong version of `summarise`- for example, having `plyr` loaded. Perhaps try specifying `dplyr::summarise` instead of just `summarise`